# Translation of "this idea is easy to explain"

Tags: word-usage, preposition

> 1. Diese Idee ist einfach zu erklären
> 2. Diese Idee ist einfach zum erklären

I've seen both versions, but I think only 1. is correct (of course I may be wrong). If 2. is also correct, shouldn't the substantivated verb be capitalized, ie

> Diese Idee ist einfach zum Erklären

?

Comment: Except for the capitalization the second sentence is *grammatically correct*. Only semantically, it's nonsense. (And of course, with ä instead of a, but that's just a typo). Also note the SentryRaven's [comment](http://german.stackexchange.com/questions/9944/translation-of-this-idea-is-easy-to-explain#comment25580_9947)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The correct version is:

> Diese Idee ist einfach zu erklären.

You are however correct in your second statement that when *zum* is used, the *Erklären* needs to be capitalized as it becomes a noun:

> Zum Erklären benutze ich immer gerne Beispiele.

Answer (score 1):

Second one isn't correct. First one can be used. Yes, if the second one was correct, you would have to capitalize "Erklären". A slightly awkward, but correct sentence exemplifying this would be "Die Erklärung dieser Idee ist einfach". I probably would say "Dies ist einfach zu erklären" (leaving out the "idea" out completely) though - the something you're trying to explain is likely inferrable from context.

Comment: Yes, I used "idea" just to give a bit of context, but the question is really about this kind of construction in general.

Answer (score 1):

1st is correct. While the 2nd is not utterly wrong (and you are right about the capitlization) and still understandable, it sounds ankward and I wouldn't use it.

Comment: The second example however changes the meaning of the sentence. His first examples states: *The idea is easy to explain.* whereas his second example, although somewhat crudely, states: *It is pretty easy to explain, using this idea*. The idea is used as the instrument and not as the object being explained.

Comment: Nein, das wäre "Mit dieser Idee ist es einfach zu erklären". Die zweite Version ist einfach Murks aber womöglich hier und das Mundart.

Comment: @userunknown This is why I said it was somewhat crude. It's obviously not the correct sentence structure or common, but with the way it's written, it would make *the idea* to the instrument.